# Системные администраторы, используете ли вы текстовые файловые менеджеры?

Tags: интерфейс

В колледже учат использованию таких текстовых файловых менеджеров как Norton Commander, Far Manager и схожих с ними, и преподаватель говорит, что они нам понадобятся. Скажите, пожалуйста, правда ли это и кто-то вообще их использует в настоящей работе?

Comment: [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/)

Comment: использую far. через conemu. Постоянно.  Почему они не имеют права использоваться? вот нортон уже врят ли нужен. последняя версия от 98 года. А FAR отличный  файловик.

Comment: Тоже midnight commander (часто его называют MC),  а также иногда dired в emacs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Производительность айтишника в разы больше в текстовых программах, особенно когда обе руки на клавиатуре.

Выцеливание мышкой в нужный файл отнимает больше времени и теряется сосредоточенность на нужном действии.

MC или FAR пользуются и адепты юниксоидов и сторонники майкрософт.

Одним из важнейших приемуществ является возможность запуститься на headless сервере по ssh и в компортовой консоли.

И ещё простые программы удобнее для обучения потому как не нужно запоминать интерфейс менеджера, а можно перейти к принципу действий с файлами.

Answer (score 3):

Да, и не только файловые менеджеры. Еще текстовые браузеры, редакторы кода, проигрыватель музыки, email-клиенты, мессенжеры, тонны всевозможных утилит, ну и само-собой командная строка. Куда же без нее!?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая тулза в правом нижнем углу? похоже на htop c добавками

Comment: @nörbörnën https://github.com/nicolargo/glances

Comment: @nörbörnën у `htop` чуть-чуть приятнее интерфейс, но реализация отрисовки этого интерфейса очень не оптимизирована. Когда я запускаю `htop` чтобы посмотреть что именно грузит систему, выясняется что максимально грузят систему два процесса - сам `htop` и терминал, в котором она запущена. Отказался. Обычный `top` гораздо более гибкий (в плане количества параметров запуска с командной строки). Ну а `glances` может работать как сервер, то есть без отрисовки, а клиент с отрисовкой запускать по потребностям. Есть еще красивый с графиками https://github.com/aristocratos/bashtop